# Compile Generated C++ Code Using VC++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, code-generation

I need to write a program that generate c++ code, compile it, and run it, so I finished the code generation part, and wrote it to a file called GeneratedCode.cpp. Now I'm stuck at the compile part, I wrote:

```
system(R"(call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat")");
system(R"(call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat")");
system("cl GeneratedCode.cpp");
```

First of all, is this the right way to do this? Info about this subject is quite scarce, especially for VC++. If it is, then I have problems both when using an IDE or not.

When using an IDE it gives me: "GeneratedCode.cpp(2): fatal error C1034: iostream: no include path set". I'm using iostream header of course.

When running the exe directly, it gives me: " 'cl' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file". Even though I called vcvarsall.bat and vcvars32.bat.

Comment: The environment set up in the batch scripts will be lost as soon as the command shells created by the `system` calls exit (`call` is a no-op in this context). You can try using `&&' to chain multiple commands within a single system call, or just write a batch script for the whole process and invoke that.

Comment: @doynax Thank you very much, that worked. Wish I could rate things right now.

Comment: If anyone is interested in the complete code of the program that generates c++ code, compile it to dll, and run it, you can find it here: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/206145/#msg977248

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each call to `system` or `_wsystem` creates a new environment which is lost when the call terminates.  If your program requires environment variables to be set up like the Visual C++ Command Prompt's `LIB`, `INCLUDE`, etc. then you aren't going to succeed by calling `system` multiple times.

Here are your options, in the order that I would recommend them:

1. Eschew `system` all together.  Set up the required environment block for `cl.exe` to work properly with string concatenation functions, as demonstrated [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682009(v=vs.85).aspx), and call [`CreateProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) with that environment.
2. Have your program write a batch file that contains all the prerequisite commands for `cl.exe` to work properly, call `system` on that, then delete the batch file.
3. Chain the commands together with `&&` and call `system` once with a big string of multiple commands.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer.